# Enforce correct property use

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type that represents a user with their login and given name:

```
export interface User {
  login: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Now I want to query an API using that user's login:

```
const formatLogin (login: string) => login.toLowerCase().trim();
const getUser = (login: string) => ajax(`${API}/users/${formatLogin(login)}`);
```

This works. Later in my code I might use:

```
getUser(this.user.name);
```

**but** that's an error. It should be `this.user.login`. They are both strings, so TypeScript doesn't complain.

Is there a way to enforce that a property is used using TypeScript?

I have tried using `export type Username = string` but that doesn't work because `name` still satisfies that type since it's just a `string`. I've also tried `export interface Username {}` which doesn't work with `formatLogin` which requires string methods `toLowerCase` and `trim`. `interface Username extends String {}` has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use so-called [branded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895#issuecomment-142428454), following the example set in the sources of [TypeScript compiler itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/types.ts#L52):

```
export type LoginString = string & { __loginBrand: any};

export interface User {
  login: LoginString;
  name: string;
}


const formatLogin = (login: string) => login.toLowerCase().trim();
const getUser = (login: LoginString) => { };

let user: User;

formatLogin(user.login); // ok
getUser(user.name); // error
```

You have to manually cast ordinary string to `LoginString` type when you are initializing `User` object, you don't have to provide actual value for `__loginBrand` - it's for typechecking only.

Another approach, suggested also by @estus, is to use destructured object as a kind of named parameters for API. It's not type-checked, but any mismatch is very noticeable, provided that all names are consistently used everywhere:

```
   export interface GetUser {
       login: string;
   }
   const getUser = ({login}: GetUser) => {}

   getUser(user); // ok
   getUser({login: user.name}); // huh?
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for typing system to differentiate between those two properties because they are arbitrary strings.

This is the domain where test coverage should help eliminate human errors.

The problem could be addressed not with types but with reasonable approach to method naming that leaves no place for errors. For example, this mistake

```
getUserByLogin(this.user.name);
```

will more likely draw attention.

Depending on the case, `getUser` could accept not a string but a reference to entire object and get desired property from it:

```
getUser = ({ login }: User ) => ajax(`${API}/users/${formatLogin(login)}`);
```